# ZK How to handle multiple events?

Tags: events, zk

I have textbox and method which listens two events.

```
<textbox id="test" />

@Listen("onOK = #test; onBlur = #test")
public void action(Event event) {
  // do something ...
}
```

When I press Enter on the Textbox, the event  "onOK " is triggered. It's OK. 
But then when I lose focus from the Texbox the  event  "onBlur" is triggered too.  It's bad, because in that case my method "action" is called two times.
How can I cancel this second event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forward any event to another event :

I [created a fiddle where you can test it](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1h9rdns/2-forward-event).

But some explication :
In the zul :

```
<textbox id="test" forward="onOK=test.onBlur"/>
```

What says that the onOK will be forwarded to onBlur, and it will be an onBlur later on.

In java code :

```
@Listen("onBlur = #test")
public void action(Event event) {
    Clients.showNotification(event.getName() + " " + ++counter);
}
```

So now we only listen for the onBlur because onOK is forwarded to the onBlur.

Will this help your case atm, not yet.

Not calling the event => not possible, if you declare it, it will be triggered.
But how can you handle your situation :

Hold the String in your composer, and check it with the new value.
If it's equal => the event is already triggered, or there are no changes.
If it's not equal => do your stuff.

Comment: To check if the value was changed is the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need that the event be triggered when the textbox lose the focus, then you have to delete the `onBlur` part:

```
@Listen("onOK = #test")
public void action(Event event) {
    // do something ...
}
```

that's because in your code you are doing with the anotation `@listen` that every time that in the textbox with id="test" are made any of these events: an `onOk` or `onBlur` (which is the one that is trigger when the focus is lose), then the method `action` is executed.

**Update**

Now, if you need that the textbox trigger an event with `onOK` but another when lose the focus (`onBlur`) then obviously you need two diferent methods and put the `listen` tag in both but with its own behavior and conditions, like this:

```
@Listen("onOK = #test")
public void action(Event event) {
    // do something when Ok...
}

@Listen("onBlur = #test")
public void anotherAction(Event event) {
    // do something when loses focus...
}
```

Comment: I need these both events `onOK`  and  `onBlur`. And they have to call one method (with the same actions). 
When I typed something in `textbox` and then lose focus the event `onBlur` is triggered. It is OK ! 
But when the first I pressed Enter and `onOK` is treggered after that I don't need   `onBlur` event to be treggered.